# Installed Pillow but not being able to import it in Python

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

I want to install Pillow library. I installed it through:

```
pip install Pillow
```

when I want to import Pillow, I use this code:

```
import PIL
```

and I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

All the processes of installation and import:
[image]

Comment: Make sure it installed to the right place and that place is part of your Python path.

Comment: Have you named your own Python script as `PIL.py` ?

Comment: @MarkRansom How should I change the installation path?

Comment: The way I do it is to run pip while I'm in the directory that Python itself is installed in.

Comment: @MarkRansom It didn't help.

Comment: @MarkSetchell no, should I do that?

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: NO! That is something to definitely avoid as it would clash with the real Pillow.

Comment: Try running this to see what you are using and where it is looking: `import sys; print(sys.executable, sys.version, *sys.path, sep="\n")` Then click [edit] and paste the output into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me on Windows with the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall Pillow
```